# How do l remove duplicate rows while using 'PARTITION' clause and using JOINS

Tags: sql

```
Select dea.continent
     , dea.location
     , dea.date
     , dea.population 
     , vac.new_vaccinations
     , SUM (cast(vac.new_vaccinations as bigint)) 
           OVER (PARTITION BY dea.date, dea.location 
                 ORDER BY dea.date, dea.location) as TotalVac
From PortifolioProjects.dbo.CovidDeath dea 
Join PortifolioProjects.dbo.CovidVaccinations vac 
    On dea.location = vac.location 
   AND dea.date = vac.date 
Where dea.continent is not null 
  and vac.new_vaccinations > 1 
Order by 2,3
```

Comment: THE REST OF THE CODE....From PortifolioProjects.dbo.CovidDeath dea
Join PortifolioProjects.dbo.CovidVaccinations vac
 On dea.location = vac.location
  AND dea.date = vac.date
Where dea.continent is not null and vac.new_vaccinations > 1
Order by 2,3

Comment: DATABASE LINK - https://ourworldindata.org/covid-deaths

Comment: Select distinct continent, location,... From ( your query) as t order by 1.2